# Updating Dataframe entry based on Lookup from another Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes. I would like update entry to column of the 2nd dataframe by checking values under Column CELLNAME in both dataframes.

So if a CELLNAME entry is  found in both then the 2nd Dataframe will update its entry as Yes in the column titled Status. If no match found then Entry will be No.

This is the code I have so far but it is not working:

```
df1=pd.read_csv('Test 1.csv')
df2=pd.read_csv('Test 1 with No Status.csv')
df2['Status']=np.where(df1['CELLNAME']=df2['CELLNAME'],'yes','no')
df2.to_csv('Test 1 with Status.csv',index=False)
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please do not post links to data or code. Come up with a small reproducing example that we can copy and paste.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `isin`:

```
df2["STATUS"] = df2["CELLNAME"].isin(df1["CELLNAME"])

>>> df2
    TMUK Cell  CELLNAME  STATUS
0       29998  29998A12    True
1       29998  29998B12    True
2       29998  29998C12    True
3       55098  55098A12    True
4       55098  55098B12    True
5       55098  55098C12    True
6       55104  55104B12    True
7       55108  55108A12    True
8       55108  55108B12    True
9       55108  55108C12   False
10      57255  57255A12   False
11      57255  57255B12   False
12      57255  57255C12   False
```

If you want "yes"/"no" instead of True/False:

```
df2["STATUS"] = df2["CELLNAME"].isin(df1["CELLNAME"]).map({True: "yes", False: "no"})
```

Comment: Thanks, i have just tried and it does the job i was looking for!